# Apache HttpClient receiving "406 Not Acceptable" error

Tags: java, http, rss, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm writing a podcast downloader using Java and Apache HttpClient.  It works fine for most RSS feeds, but this one is failing with a "406 Not Acceptable" error.

The link is http://sqrpt.com/feed/podcast/

The response I get back is:

```
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable [Server: nginx/1.12.0, Date: Sat, 03 Jun 2017 03:40:17 GMT, Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1, Content-Length: 226, Connection: keep-alive] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1,Content-Length: 226,Chunked: false]}}
```

My Java code is:

```
   HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setUserAgent( "Mozilla/5.0" ).build();
   HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet( url );
   httpGet.setHeader( "Accept", "*/*" );
   httpGet.setHeader( "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch" );
   httpGet.setHeader( "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8" );
   HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute( httpGet );
   return httpResponse.getEntity();
```

I'm unsure what to do to debug this.  Most posts say its the **Accept** header at fault.  I've set mine to accept everything, yet am still failing.

When I go to the site in Chrome I get the following headers.  Could it be the 304 return code that is causing the problem?

```
General
Request URL:http://sqrpt.com/feed/podcast/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Remote Address:192.185.32.200:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
view source
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Sat, 03 Jun 2017 03:46:27 GMT
ETag:"c06764644cd3ec282be2807a54a3484c"
Server:nginx/1.12.0

Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:sqrpt.com
If-Modified-Since:Fri, 02 Jun 2017 01:36:27 GMT
If-None-Match:"c06764644cd3ec282be2807a54a3484c"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
```

What else can I try?

Comment: Am seeing nginx in response headers. I used to face this issue, as a workaround was flushing the nginx content caching and it was working fine. My 406 was because of conflicts between nginx and upstream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it checks the User-Agent. I got it to work with the following user agent:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setUserAgent( "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36" ).build();
```